# What happened to my comments?

Tags: discussion, comments

I apologise for any forgetfulness, but I believe that I commented under [this Answer](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/38738) to thank the Answerer and express my gratitude to learn more about the context.  What happened to it?

How can I determine if any of comments were edited or deleted? I haven't received any notices.

Comment: In my opinion, the best way to express your appreciation is to accept the answer or up vote it. Accepting isn't permanent. If someone provides a better answer later, you can change which one best answers your question.

Comment: "What happened to my comments?", by the way, not #"What occurred to my comments?".

Answer (score 5):

[Read this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Pay attention to the first three words:

> Comments are temporary

Also, under "When shouldn't I comment":

> Compliments which do not add new information

Note that moderators occasionally "trim" the conversations in comments if they become "too chatty," too distracting, too hostile, too lengthy, too sidetracked, or unconstructive.

Sometimes *thank you* comments will get [flagged](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/169994/should-a-thank-you-comment-be-flagged). Discussions about the appropriateness of *thank you* comments on SE have [gone on for years now](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126180/is-it-acceptable-to-write-a-thank-you-in-a-comment).

You can read more about this [here](https://ux.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1565/how-to-determine-when-a-comment-is-too-chatty-or-not-constructive), too.

Comment: +1 for the all-important point that *comments are **temporary*** (and imho, one of the mods' specific *jobs* is to tidy up after those of us who leave too many irrelevant "chatty" comments). I have once or twice posted a comment asking the mods to leave some earlier comment thread because I think it's highly relevant but too long to incorporate into an answer. But it's up to the mods to make a judgement call in each specific case.

Comment: [Also relevant](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers): "Please do **not** add a comment on your question or on an answer to say ‘Thank you’." <emphasis in [original](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)>