# About mods' removing comments so that (it seems to me) nothing inconvenient for mods remains

Tags: discussion

I made [**a question.**](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/208972/the-phrase-trade-in-from-an-article)

It's up to the readers if I saw an answer had come before the mod deleted the post itself. And the mod noticed the answer afterward and reopened it. I said as you can see at the comment line "I will delete after an hour", which is the violation to the etiquette of the SE and which I didn't know. (I apologize for this point.) But removing the comments which now as if **I** am trying to delete the post and hiding the seemingly inconvenient comments to the mod? It looks like even though the mod deleted the post and reopened it again (which you can track back) seems inconvenient to the mod? (I virtually did **nothing**).

I got a message from the community itself for the further improvement and I told them it's OK, I will abide by it. But removing the comments at mods' will so that as if (for now) I am the one who messed the entire things completely?

I am beginning to doubt the handling by mods. I am sorry.

Comment: I removed the comments to give @J.R. a chance to handle the situation. I didn't understand what had happened, and my comments added to the confusion. Meta is a more appropriate place for this discussion regardless.

Comment: Will you please stop adding an extra space between parentheses? They are not supposed to be there. (See [this answer on ELU](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/6035/18220)). I am tired of cleaning this up for you; I've done it countless times.

Comment: Having never interacted on that post, I'm a bit confused about the turn of events. . . It seems J.R. initially deleted the post but later reopened and marked it as a duplicate? Either way, your accusation is far off. This isn't a popularity contest and mods are just doing thankless voluntary work, and they have better things to do with their time than make it look like someone did something to an online post.

Comment: You're mischaracterizing what they do. They nominate, and the *community* opts to elect them or not, so this is a democracy, but that's besides the point. You don't seem to have much experience moderating SE sites at the very least, or you'd know it's more like shoveling feces out of sight than an authoritarian monarchy who imposes their will on the community. It's **OK** to disagree with mods' decision (I have numerous times), and this meta is the place to make your case. (BTW sorry for the blunt tone)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what the other comments said, but you can delete your own comment and then flag J.R.'s [response](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/208972/the-phrase-trade-in-from-an-article#comment401626_208972) to it (specifically, flag it as "no longer needed"). There's no reason to keep these two comments around.

(By the way, if the answer was upvoted or accepted at the time you went to delete the question, you would not be able to delete it anyway.)

Answer (score 9):

Yes, you asked a question. And then you wrote a comment beneath your own question saying that you would delete that question in one hour.

I don't know why you would want to keep a question open for an hour and then delete it, but that would not have been an appropriate thing to do. People might invest their time writing a comment or an answer, and then that would would have all been for nothing after you deleted your question.

For that reason, I immediately deleted your question after I saw your comment. However, right after I deleted your question, I realized that someone had already left an answer. When I noticed that answer, I realized that deleting the question was the wrong course of action, so I undeleted the question, and then closed it as a duplicate instead.

Some further comments beneath the post were later deleted. I had nothing to do with that action, but I support it. Those comments were about your confusion with the situation and are therefore obsolete. Your question was about the word *trade-in*. Any comments about something unrelated to that should be deleted because they are not relevant to the question.

Comment: Thanks for explaining.  I can see how this might have been confusing, but I don’t think anything bad came of having the question temporarily deleted, and overall I think the situation was handled quite well.

Answer (score 8):

So, this issue is still gnawing at you, eh?

> How much should we need to thank for mods who nominated themselves by their own will?  We are not slaves of mods or itinerary servants for mods. Thank you. (Here, mods delete their comments according to their "favourites" even in the meta. Ha.)

Sadly, [we have thrashed through this before](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1268/what-happened-to-my-comments/1270#1270), but I will present some facts one more time:

1) The Stack Exchange emphasizes that **[comments are temporary](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment)** (sometimes called [*ephemeral*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/312001/how-are-comments-ephemeral)), and encourages moderators to clean up comments that promote discord, do not add anything constructive, or have outlived their usefulness.

2) We don't delete comments according to "favorites". I just checked the main site: As of this writing, you have had 157 comments deleted. I have had 937 comments deleted, ColleenV has had 929 comments deleted, and snailboat has had 1,407 comments deleted. So, for every one comment of yours that has disappeared, 20 moderator comments have also been swept into the dustbin.

3) If you don't want your comments deleted, then don't whine about petty things, make inaccurate accusations against other members of the Stack Exchange, or engage in protracted arguments. Your comment has a better chance of staying on the site longer when you say something useful and constructive – but even useful and constructive comments can sometimes become obsolete over time.

It's time to stop regarding the deletion of a comment as a personal insult.